# CRUD - PHP PDO Error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I Have a Problem With Source Code PHP PDO . I Try make a CRUD with PHP PDO , but when i try source code for delete and when I run a script the Data do not want to be erased .. I apologize if my speaking was nothing wrong, I am from Indonesian

Thank's Before

Script function delete :

```
public function deleteData($id)
    {
        // fungsi menghapus data dari database
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->sql = "DELETE FROM student WHERE id=:id";
    $this->q = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    $this->q->bindParam(":id",$this->id);
    $this->q->execute();
    return true;
    }
```

Script delete.php

```
<?php
     include "belajar_crud.php";
     $obj = new crud;
     $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id']:'';
     $obj->deleteData($id);
?>
```

Comment: What is the exact unexpected behavior? You need to show your code which is causing this unexpected behavior?

Comment: Did you get any errors? The code in itself looks okay, but maybe the table name or field name is wrong, the id could contain an invalid character, or you could lack the proper credentials to delete rows.

Comment: This code delete.php :
https://gist.github.com/RiskyFeryansyah/0f0d968c7d0bd82c5bc6

This Code Function delete PHP :
https://gist.github.com/RiskyFeryansyah/b6951baa0ed4af7a9a70

Comment: I do not see an error code while on the run, but when I try to delete the data would not be erased

Comment: It looks like you've started to write your own database layer. Keep in mind that any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) already has one that's quite powerful, so this is usually counter-productive.

Comment: @tadman : thanks for reply hehe , but I dont use the framework laravel, I use pure PHP

Comment: @RiskyFeryansyah Yes, I've noticed. That's why I'm saying you probably *should*. Laravel is PHP as well, but it's a very capable platform that gives you significantly more powerful tools than the base PHP library.

Comment: @tadman : hehehe thank you for your advice , I am also willing to learn laravel :D heheh .

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$this->q = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
```

Into this:

```
$this->q = $this->dbh->prepare($this->sql);
```

This is the only error I see in the code...
If this is not the case, you need to provide more information.

Comment: Thank's for replay , I've replaced it, but when I run the data still do not want to be erased

Answer (score 0):

why you no try this?

config.php:

```
define('HOST','your host');
define('BD','your database');
define('USER','your user');
define('PASS','your password');
```

BD.class.php:

```
class BD{
     private static $conn;
     public function __construct(){}
     public function conn(){
          if(is_null(self::$conn)){
               self::$conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='.BD.'',''.USER.'',''.PASS.'');
          }
          return self::$conn;
     }
}
```

your code of delete:

```
@BD::conn();
$query = @BD::conn()->prepare("DELETE FROM YOURTABLE WHERE ID = ?");
if($query->execute(array($this->id))){
    echo "<script>alert('Delete Successful');</script>";
}
```